# How to read serial data (Array) sent by an Arduino in Visual Basic?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, visual-studio, arduino, serial-port

I have 8 sensors I read the values from analog ports and I store them in an array. How can I read those values in Visual Basic?

I have a timer that sends '*' to Arduino from VB and then the Arduino returns sensor values. I tried receiving array data in Arduino by sending '&' to make sure that I'm putting the right values in my array.

Arduino code:

```
uint8_t i;
unsigned char c;
char data[6];
bool rd = false;
String dataString = "";
int sensor;
uint8_t b;
static const uint8_t analog_pins[] = {A0, A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6, A7};
int myVals[7];

#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>

const int chipSelect = 4;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println(A0);
  while (!Serial) {
    ;
  }
  if (!SD.begin(chipSelect)) {
    return;
  }
  File dataFile = SD.open("datalog.txt", FILE_WRITE);
  if (dataFile) {
    dataFile.println("Gas Sesnor TEST results :");
    dataFile.close();
  }
}

void loop() {
}

void serialEvent() {
  c = Serial.read();
  if  (c == '*') {
    for (b = 0 ; b <= 7 ; b++) {
      sensor = analogRead(analog_pins[b]);
      myVals[b] = sensor;
      Serial.println(sensor);
      dataString = String(sensor) + "\n";
      File dataFile = SD.open("datalog.txt", FILE_WRITE);
      if (dataFile) {
        dataFile.println(dataString);
        dataFile.close();
      }
    }
  }
  if (c == '&') {
    for (b = 0; b <= 7; b++) {
      Serial.println(myVals[b]);
    }
  }
}
```

VB code so far:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        SerialPort1.WriteLine("*")
        receivedData = ReceiveSerialData()
        RichTextBox1.Text = receivedData
        RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = RichTextBox1.TextLength
        RichTextBox1.ScrollToCaret()
Function ReceiveSerialData() As Integer

        Try
            Dim Incoming As String
            Try
                Incoming = SerialPort1.ReadExisting()
                If Incoming Is Nothing Then
                    Return 0
                Else
                    Return Incoming
                End If
            Catch ex As TimeoutException
                Return "Error: Serial Port read timed out."
            End Try
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try

    End Function
```

It keeps returning 0. Please help me.

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Potential areas for faults are (1) Arduino not sending any data, (2) Not reading the SerialPort correctly, (3) Returning `String`s as `Integer`s (most likely culprit), (4) Code operating quickly and it is working as intended but your textbox is being overwritten with later values that = 0. More likely a  combination of all of the above. `Option Explicit`, `Option Strict`!

Comment: Your arduino code is incorrect, the line which states "Serial.println(myVals[b]);" should actually state "Serial.println(analogRead(analog_pins[b]);" this is because your myVals array maybe empty (contain zero's)